# Operator Class of an Index in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, indexing, operators

How can I learn which operator class is used by an already created index in PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can query the system catalog.
There can be multiple operator classes for multi-column indexes.

```
SELECT opcname
FROM  (
   SELECT unnest(indclass) AS ind_op
   FROM   pg_index
   WHERE  indexrelid = 'index_schema.index_name'::regclass
   ) i 
JOIN   pg_opclass o ON o.oid = i.ind_op;
```

`indclass` is of type `oidvector` which can be unnested like any array. This way, you get multiple lines for a multi-column index. More details about the catalog tables in the manual [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/catalog-pg-index.html) and [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/catalog-pg-opclass.html).

If `index_schema` is in your `search_path` (and comes first, in case of duplicate index names), you don't have to schema-qualify the name.

Comment: More most case, I think the index_schema is 'public',

Comment: @zw963: In simple cases, yes. But the index lives in the same schema as its parent table, which can be most any schema, especially in multi-user environments.